# Automatically run the script if a new row is added to a specific column

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am developing a web app where the admin can add the residents name and few particulars about them there. So after adding the data there, I have few formulas written in appscript so that it will automatically fill up some columns there in my google sheet without doing it manually. So guys can anyone here help where if there is a row of data is added to column B, it should trigger the coding I have done in the appscript. I have attached the images and my code to explain myself better. Thank you.

[image]

**Code.gs**

```
var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bM8l6JefFsPrlJnTWf56wOhnuSjdIwg3hMbY1tN1Zp8/edit#gid=531487589";

function doPost(e) {

  var rowData = [];

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("PaypalData");

  rowData.push(new Date(e.parameter.payment_date));
  rowData.push(e.parameter.item_number);
  rowData.push(e.parameter.option_selection1);
  rowData.push(e.parameter.payment_status);
  rowData.push(e.parameter.payment_gross);
  rowData.push(e.parameter.mc_currency);
  rowData.push(e.parameter.payment_fee);
  rowData.push(e.parameter.first_name);
  rowData.push(e.parameter.last_name);
  rowData.push(e.parameter.payer_email);
  rowData.push(e.parameter.residence_country);
  rowData.push(e.parameter.txn_id);
  
  sheet.appendRow(rowData);
}

function getLast(range) {
    var getResult = function(range) {
        if (!((range.getNumRows() > 1 && range.getNumColumns() == 1) || (range.getNumRows() == 1 && range.getNumColumns() > 1))) {
            throw new Error("Please input one row or one column.");
        }
        var v = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], range.getValues());
        var f = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], range.getFormulas());
        var i;
        for (i = v.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (v[i] != "" || f[i] != "") break;
        }
        return i + 1;
    };
    if (Array.isArray(range)) {
        return range.map(function(e) {
            return getResult(e);
        });
    } else {
        try {
            range.getA1Notation();
        } catch (e) {
            throw new Error("Inputted value is not a range.");
        }
        return getResult(range);
    }
}

function username(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("USERNAMES");
  ss.getRange("A2").setFormula('=IF(ISBLANK(B2:B),"",(B2:B &"."&substitute(substitute(lower(C2:C),"jalan","jln")," ","")))');
  var range1 = sheet.getRange("B:B");
  var lr = getLast(range1); // Retrieve last row of column 2.
  var fillDownRange = sheet.getRange(2, 1, lr-1);
  ss.getRange("A2").copyTo(fillDownRange);
}

function noOfPaid(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("USERNAMES");
  ss.getRange("F2").setFormula("=IF(ISBLANK(B2:B), ,(COUNTIF('Payment Configuration'!A:A,A2:A) + COUNTIF('Payment Configuration'!E:E,A2:A)))");
  var range1 = sheet.getRange("B:B");
  var lr = getLast(range1); // Retrieve last row of column 2.
  var fillDownRange = sheet.getRange(2, 6, lr-1);
  ss.getRange("F2").copyTo(fillDownRange);
}

function fullAddress(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("USERNAMES");
  ss.getRange("I2").setFormula('=join(", ",{B2,UPPER(C2),"BANDAR PUTERI KLANG"})');
  var range1 = sheet.getRange("B:B");
  var lr = getLast(range1); // Retrieve last row of column 2.
  var fillDownRange = sheet.getRange(2, 9, lr-1);
  ss.getRange("I2").copyTo(fillDownRange);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trigger script on google spreadsheet when a new row is inserted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29043479/trigger-script-on-google-spreadsheet-when-a-new-row-is-inserted)

Comment: @WillMetcher No bro because I only I only want to trigger the three functions when the column B in "USERNAMES" sheet is modified bro. Can you help me with it?

Comment: @WillMetcher Bro I tried the coding but somehow it shows an error for me bro. Can you help me to solve the problem. https://script.google.com/home/projects/1qVpJ1XapP2Mz_xS1MuFHHH_SSPjyQEKTeg4oUPtPPJMPnWfE0afvg1oR/edit - Link to appscript

Answer (score 0):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getSheetName() === "USERNAMES" && e.range.columnStart == 2) {
    // run functions
  }
}
```

Comment: @WaiHaLee Bro I tried the coding but somehow it shows an error for me bro. Can you help me to solve the problem. https://script.google.com/home/projects/1qVpJ1XapP2Mz_xS1MuFHHH_SSPjyQEKTeg4oUPtPPJMPnWfE0afvg1oR/edit - Link to my appscript

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: My google sheet is keep on loading by itself bro. Suddenly it is not showing any fomula's there. It is like the sheet is fluctuating

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bM8l6JefFsPrlJnTWf56wOhnuSjdIwg3hMbY1tN1Zp8/edit#gid=281217946 - Link to my google sheet

Comment: I open the links for editor bro would you mind have a look on the problem

Answer (score 0):

It's all wrong, as far as I can tell.

For example: the function `doPost()` appends a new row on the sheet 'PaypalData'. But the columns of the new row (parameters of `e`) don't fit with columns on the sheet. Not to mention that the sheet 'PaypalData' has no real data at all. It gets the data from another spreadsheet via `IMPORTRANGE(...)` formula in the cell `A3`. And all the 'data' disappears as soon as you add something in the range of `IMPORTRANGE` That is the mess!

The task 'to add a new row on some sheets' is quite simply by itself. And you got the more or less correct example how it can be done already.

It looks like you just copy/paste too much someone's code without faintest idea how it works. I'm sorry, but you need to start from something less complicated.

Well, you can try to fix your code a bit...

The function `onEdit()`:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() == "USERNAMES" && e.range.getColumn() == 2) {
    username(e.source);
    noOfPaid(e.source);
    fullAddress(e.source);
  }
}
```

The function `username()`:

```
function username(ss) {
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("USERNAMES");
  ss.getRange("A2").setFormula('=IF(ISBLANK(B2:B),"",(B2:B &"."&substitute(substitute(lower(C2:C),"jalan","jln")," ","")))');
  var range1 = sheet.getRange("B:B");
  var lr = getLast(range1); // Retrieve last row of column 2.
  var fillDownRange = sheet.getRange(2, 1, lr-1);
  ss.getRange("A2").copyTo(fillDownRange);
}
```

Etc... Instead of:

```
function noOfPaid(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
...
```

```
function fullAddress(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  ...
```

You need to use:

```
function fullAddress(ss){
  ...
```

```
function noOfPaid(ss){
  ...
```

Since you can't open the spreadsheet by URL if this spreadsheet already was open.

This makes your code to woks to some extent. It will copy the formulas in columns `A`, `F` and `I` when you will change column `B`. But it looks pretty awful anyway.